# Use Regex to Replace the Starting substring

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

The following statement needs to be replaced, as in the following code

```
page_url.replace("www.", "");
```

This needs to be done with the use of regex. Please let me know the method of achieving the same.
Logically, it needs to replace the "www." with "" **if and only if the string starts with www.**.

Comment: The `^` character anchors to the start of the input string.

Comment: I suggest you bone up on regexp basics, starting with a tutorial or overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"www.test.com".replace(/^www\./, "") // returns "test.com"`

or in long form:

```
var regex = /^www\./;
var stringToMatch = "www.test.com";

var result = stringToMatch.replace(regex, ""); // "test.com"
```

where the `/^www\./` defines the regex object. This is made up of:

- `/` start of the regex
- `^` start of string, means this match must appear at the begining
- `www` match the characters `www`
- `\.` match the character `.`. We must escape it with `\` because in regex `.` means match anything
- `/` end of the regex definition

If you wan't to play about with the regex to see how it works, try it in this web regex tester: https://regex101.com/r/7ErXz8/2

Comment: Also can you please explain what is being done here. I am not that great with regex.